# RxJava2 - order of subscribing in chain

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

In RxJava 1 downstream Observable was observer of upstream Observable. Chain was subscribed from bottom to top. If source of items was achieved than emitting of items started.

How it works in RxJava2? I tried to used logging. Upstream Observable´s onSubscribe callback is called before downstream´s. Items are emitted from source after last (the lowest) operator in chain is subscribed.

Behavior of subscribing of all chain is very nonintuitive for me. Can you describe behavior during subscribing? 
Method subscribeActual of upstream operator is called by Observer? And Observable call notification onSubscribe of downstream Observable?

Comment: `subscribe` travels upstream and the `onXXX` travel downstream, now with the so-called inversion of control for unsubscription by providing a "callback" via `onSubscribe`. What are you trying to achieve? If you implement `DisposableObserver` instead of the plain `Observer`, you don't have to worry much about unsubscription in the chain.

Comment: I want to know how exactly RxJava2 works.
Observable.just(1,2,3)
.filter(x -> x > 0).
.doOnSubscribe(log("o1 subscribed")
.map(x -> x + 1)
.doOnSubscribe(log("o2 subscribed")
.subscribe()
RxJava1: just with filter create observable o1, observable o1 with map create observable o2. When I subscribe observable o2, than callback o2 subscribed is called. After them map is subscribed and map subscribe doOnSubscribe(1), callback o1 subscribed is called. RxJava 2: Callback onSubscribe is not called when observable is subscribed but later. Why? Can you recommend me best publication?

Comment: There is an explicit preparation step in RxJava 2 in the form of `onSubscribe` that allows wiring up the unsubscription chain before any item is emitted. `doOnSubscribe` hooks into this downstream-directed event. v1 had no such thing so `doOnSubscribe` had to hook into the `subscribe` path going upstream. This had the trouble that flows were partially established on that call.

Comment: Perhaps you can understand the v2 structure by reading the [Reactive-Streams](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#reactive-streams) specification and ignoring the backpressure-related parts.

Comment: Is possible to log correct time when Observable is subscribed? In the sense of RxJava doOnSubscribe callback. When I need to practically demonstrate how subscribing in chain work.

Comment: There are an RxJavaPlugins hooks that intercept the execution between `subscribe` and `subscribeActual`.

Comment: subscribeActual determines beginning execution of Observable (dual for subscribe of Rx1)?

Comment: It's the equivalent of `Observable.OnSubscribe.call()`.